# Simple PHP text file write update

Tags: php, bash

I need a form with two fields and a submit button to update the RTMP_URL & STREAM_KEY without affecting the rest of the data in the file named "stream"

```
RTMP_URL _______
STREAM_KEY ________
SUBMIT
```

This is the file "stream" which needs to be updated via the form

```
#!/bin/bash
RTMP_URL=
STREAM_KEY=
while :
do
    video4linux -n -t 0 -w 960 -h 540 -fps 25 -b 500000 -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -metadata title="camera" -f flv $RTMP_URL/$STREAM_KEY
    sleep 2 done

done
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: where are you codes which does the file operation? you should post it also

Comment: Use `exec()` and set the variables using the environment.

Comment: Thanks Jack, any chance you could point me toward a tutorial on this?